# eBay API GetItemTransactions TransactionID returns wrong result

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I use XML based request from eBay towards their `GetItemTransactions` method, and the XML request looks like this:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
 <GetItemTransactionsRequest xmlns='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents' > 
 <RequesterCredentials>  
 <eBayAuthToken>//my auth token</eBayAuthToken> 
 </RequesterCredentials> 
 <ItemID>131966550509</ItemID> 
 <NumberOfDays>6</NumberOfDays> 
 <Pagination>
 <EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage>
 <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
 </Pagination> 
 <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel> 
 <OutputSelector>ReturnedTransactionCountActual,FeedbackScore,UserID,CurrentPrice,Title,ItemID,CreatedDate,TransactionPrice,QuantityPurchased,TransactionID</OutputSelector>
 </GetItemTransactionsRequest>
```

What I find odd, is the fact that I get completely wrong results for the `TransactionID` parameter, in which case for most transactions of the item the `TransactionID` is returned like this:

```
TransactionID

100000000000
100000000000
100000000000
100000000000
100000000000
100000000000
100000000000
100000000000
100000000000
100000000000
100000000000
```

I have also tried using their `OrderLineItemID` field which is a combination of `ItemId-TransactionID` to make an unique identifier, but for it I also get the following:

```
100000000000-100000000000
```

Is there anything else that I can use as an unique identifier from eBay or does anyone know why the results that I get are incorrect?

Comment: Anyone guys?? =)